# Kafka-streams corrupt message-handling semantics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, corruption

I notice that Kafka records have a CRC field. If a record in a log file corrupts (e.g. a single bit in the middle of the message gets flipped), what would I expect to see in the streams application in the case of:

- The topic is replicated
- The topic is not replicated

Since we are using Avro, I can imagine one of the following occurs:

- Underlying infrastructure detects CRC error and sources it from another broker
- The DeserializationExceptionHandler kicks in
- Some other error occurs and the topology falls over or the message is skipped, according to policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CRC errors, a exception should be thrown in your Streams application when it tries to deserializer the records. And thus, the `DeserializationExceptionHandler` kicks in.

In Kafka, all read/writes are handled by the partition leader, and follower brokers only replicate data passively in the background and don't serve any read/write from clients.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the Avro deserialiser actively checks the CRC before deserialising? Otherwise it's a dig around the code tomorrow :)

Comment: AFAIK, CRC is checked by the consumer before the deserializer is applied. So it's not the responsibility of the deserializer to check CRC -- the consumer does it automatically.